# JTextPane does not go to a new line?

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

I'm displaying RSS feed in my JTextPanel. The result displayed doesn't go to a new line. How can I insert '\n' in a JTextPane? Thanks!

writeNews class:

```
 public String writeNews() 
        {
            String result = "";
            
            try 
        {               
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            URL u = new URL("http://thestar.com.my.feedsportal.com/c/33048/f/534600/index.rss"); 

            Document doc = builder.parse(u.openStream());
            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
                    
            for(int i=0;i<nodes.getLength();i++) 
            {                
                Element element = (Element)nodes.item(i);           
                
                result += "\nTitle: " + getElementValue(element,"title");               
                result += "\nLink: " + getElementValue(element,"link");
                result += "\nPublish Date: " + getElementValue(element,"pubDate");
                result += "\nDescription: " + getElementValue(element,"description");

                System.out.println("Title: " + getElementValue(element,"title"));
                System.out.println("Link: " + getElementValue(element,"link"));
                System.out.println("Publish Date: " + getElementValue(element,"pubDate"));
                System.out.println("Description: " + getElementValue(element,"description"));
                System.out.println();
                
            }
        }

        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return result;
    }
```

And the result are displayed on a simple JTextPane:

```
public void news()
    {
        news = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        news.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaptionBorder);
        
        JTextPane newsTextPane = new JTextPane(); 
        newsTextPane.setContentType("text/html");
        newsTextPane.setEditable(false); 

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(newsTextPane);     
        news.add(scrollPane);   
        
        TextSamplerDemo reader = TextSamplerDemo.getInstance();
        reader.writeNews();             
        
        String rssNews = reader.writeNews();
        newsTextPane.setText(rssNews);
    
    }
```

JTextPane View:
[image: JTextPane View]

Console View:
[image: Console View]

Comment: Side-Note: Best to not use `\n` for newline character per [java best practices](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=38).

Comment: As a part of that comment, I should just say a better alternative is to have something like this: `public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");` and anywhere you want a newline, you can just add the `newline` variable. Best of luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible workaround,

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class TestLineBreak {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sb.append("Text goes here <br>"); //<br> tag to insert line breaks
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTextPane newsTextPane = new JTextPane();
        newsTextPane.setContentType("text/html");
        newsTextPane.setEditable(false);
        newsTextPane.setText(sb.toString());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(newsTextPane);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sanjay! <br> is what i needed!

Answer (score 2):

```
result += "Title: " + getElementValue(element,"title");             
result += "Link: " + getElementValue(element,"link");
result += "Publish Date: " + getElementValue(element,"pubDate");
result += "Description: " + getElementValue(element,"description");
```

When you create your `String`, you never use new lines. Either prepend the newline to the start of every line (other than the first line) or append the newline to the end of every line (other than the last line).

Comment: I've made changes. Only when I disable the setContentType("text/html") the \n works. I need to display links so I need to keep that. It's still not going to the next line.

Comment: @LilyT Since you're using HTML, why not use `<br>`?

Comment: @LilyT, if the answer was satisfactory, please accept it so future users will see what solved the problem :)

Answer (score -1):

Buddies.. 
The way above 2 answers are working is logically correct but we should take help from built-in classes and functionality that java provides.

You may also procure the following way if you are to add other functionality similar to the questioned on

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.html

Comment: Please comment on the answers themselves to add more information. Also, you cannot refer to "above answers" since the order of the appearance of the answers might be different to different users.